# Java Threads and synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a web app that uses some jars written by me.
My challenge is that i have a critical (but fast) section in my code.

1 - I have an object of a given class that has a couple of `static` fields. Let's call this class A

2 _ A exposes a not static method that access the `static` fields. for reading and writting. Lets call this method `doJob`.

3 - Every request instantiates an object of the class `A` and calls `doJob`.
`A a = new A(); a.doJob();`

4 - I assume that every request is creating a new `Thread` where `doJob` is executed.

5 - If I define `doJob` as `public synchronized void doJob () {//Do the job}` only one `Thread` at a time will be executing the method and the others will keep waiting.

The question is: Is it all right what i am saying?

Comment: Instances of objects have nothing to do with synchronization (excepting that some instances might only be used/visible in context X). I think there is a Java Trail for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, but doJob will be synchronized at instance level, so doJob method could be executed in the same time by two or more different threads on two or more instances of class A. If you want doJob to be executed only by one thread at a time (e.g because it chages static fields) you should either declare it static or synchronize the whole method body using a static field as locking object.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're trying to guard static (i.e. one per class) fields with non-static (i.e. one per object) monitors, I would say that the "only one thread at a time will be executing the method and the others will keep waiting" claim does not hold.

Comment: Hi alf and thanks for your answer. What abou adding some other static field and somewhere in the method synchronized(staticfield){//Do the job} thank you

Comment: mdev, that's one of possible approaches. Generally, though, one would like to think in terms of goals and guarantees rather than low-level details; since we don't know your goals, I cannot say whether or not it's a _good_ approach.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Marking an instance method as `synchronized` means the same that doing

```
public void myMethod() {
  synchronized(this) {
    ...
  }
}
```

So, you can only guarantee that two threads are not running the same method *of the same object*. The same method from another object can be run simultaneously.

Try to synchronize with a more "static" object. I would use the class object itself, or some static (and inmutable) member.

Comment: Hi SJuan76. I think I get what you say. would it be some static field in the class called syn and then public void myMethod() {
  synchronized(syn) {
    ...
  }
} Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you're outline is correct. and it does technically bottleneck the system while the other threads wait for access. and this is perfectly fine and normal as long as you avoid putting any heavy processing or i/o within the synchronized block.